# Form Alignment in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following HTML in bootstrap 3 that gives the following display:
[image]

The HTML it as follows.

In one row i have only one field, while on others I have 3. Is it possible with bootstrap to make all rows position "first" label on the same position? In this case, "Project Name", "Location", and "Project Value" will be aligned same position.

Thanks

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="mainForm">
         <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                        <label for="txtProjectName" class="control-label col-sm-4 col-xs-3">Project Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtProjectName" placeholder="Name of Project">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                        <label for="txtLocation" class="control-label col-sm-4 col-xs-3">Location</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtLocation" placeholder="Location">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                        <label for="txtProjectValue" class="control-label col-sm-4 col-xs-3">Project Value</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtprojectValueUsd" placeholder="Project Value (US $)">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                        <label for="txtCCCValue" class="control-label col-sm-4 col-xs-3">CCC Value</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtCCCValue" placeholder="CCC Value (US $)">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                        <label for="txtProjectValueLocal" class="control-label col-sm-4 col-xs-3">Project Value Local</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtProjectValueLocal" placeholder="Project Value Local Currency">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row top-buffer">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first two `div.row` you the `.form-group` with `.col-sm-6`. If you change it to `.col-sm-4` you will get the alignment you want.

E.g.:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtProjectName" class="control-label col-sm-4 col-xs-3">Project Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtProjectName" placeholder="Name of Project">
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a working demo http://jsfiddle.net/wmyuj7gy/.

**EDIT**:

If you want the first two rows to be full width you need to change the `.col-sm-4` to `.col-sm-12` and the inner elements to have the `.col-sm-1` and `.col-sm-11` class.

Also, you should nt use the `.form-group` class in the same `div` with the `.col-sm-*` classes because is messes with the grid's paddings.

Here is a fixed example of your code, with also some other changes in the last row to make the form perfectly aligned http://jsfiddle.net/wmyuj7gy/3/

Comment: What if I want to make "Project Name" input field span all row?

Comment: Hi Tasos, I noticed one thing. Label with ".col-sm-1" when placed inside a column of ".col-sm-12", is different from a label with ".col-sm-1" placed inside a column of ".col-sm-4" as in the case of a single row and a row with 3 columns above. I had to give the labels in the row with 3 columns a ".col-sm-3" instead to fit the above labels. Any idea?

Comment: You cannot add a `.col-sm-1` inside a `.col-sm-4` directly. In order for the bootstrap grid to work properly you need to add a `.row` inside the `.col-sm-4`. Check documentation in nesting columns http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Comment: Check this pls: http://jsfiddle.net/bhaidar/ws8e8nms/ Notice labels in row with one field and row with 3 fields.1st uses col-md-2 while others use col-md-6.As if within row of col-md-4,its divided into 12 columns by its turn. Also this problem reflects on buttons in the end,not getting aligned with rest of controls above. 10x

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ws8e8nms/2/. To fix the buttons issue I wrapped the `.form-group` that contained the buttons into a `.row` and then a `.col-xs-11.col-md-12` like you do with the rest of the form.

Comment: .form-group has the same effect of a .row? I mean I don't need a .row inside .form-group to use .col-*?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Using `.row` is not necessary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60380/discussion-between-bill-and-tasos-k).

Answer (score 0):

try this one -

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <label for="txtProjectName" class="control-label col-sm-4 col-xs-3">Project Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtProjectName" placeholder="Name of Project">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <label for="txtLocation" class="control-label col-sm-4 col-xs-3">Location</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtLocation" placeholder="Location">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <label for="txtProjectValue" class="control-label col-sm-4 col-xs-3">Project Value</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtprojectValueUsd" placeholder="Project Value (US $)">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <label for="txtCCCValue" class="control-label col-sm-4 col-xs-3">CCC Value</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtCCCValue" placeholder="CCC Value (US $)">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <label for="txtProjectValueLocal" class="control-label col-sm-4 col-xs-3">Project Value Local</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtProjectValueLocal" placeholder="Project Value Local Currency">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```